# Exclude records with specific value '*' SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am in the processing of preparing for migration to a new database system for a stock based retail store. In the current database products which have been deactivated have a leading * added to the record.

The owners do not want to bring deactivated products into the new system so this leading * is my only reference point to work from.

I need to create a SELECT query that will exclude products that have a leading * but so for to no avail.

I have tried the below

```
SELECT prdcod
FROM prdtbl
WHERE prodcod<>'*%';
```

The first 10 results returned are:

1. 71A022
2. 051116
3. 070505PRO
4. *031620
5. 458508
6. 501315
7. *070247PE
8. 370002
9. 070278STU
10. *CO20302

I suspect I may not be able to use the * as an excluding factor

Any thoughts would be appreceated

Comment: prodcod not like '*%';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in so many ways..

Using `NOT LIKE`

```
SELECT prdcod
FROM prdtbl
WHERE prodcod NOT LIKE '*%'
```

Using `LEFT/SUBSTRING`

```
SELECT prdcod
FROM prdtbl
WHERE LEFT(prodcod,1) <> '*' -- SUBSTRING(prodcod from 1 for 1) <> '*'
```

**Note :** `Not Like` is preferred approach if you have a `Index` on `prodcod` column

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SELECT prdcod
    FROM prdtbl
    WHERE prodcod not like '*%';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT prdcod
FROM prdtbl
WHERE prodcod NOT LIKE '*%';
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using "<>" operator, use "not like":

```
Select prdcod
From prdtbl
Where prodcod not like '*%';
```